# Scroll SlidingDrawer view in Android

Tags: android, scroll, slidingdrawer

I'm using a SlidingDrawer to show some selected Facebook contacts. When open, how can I make it scrollable to be  able to see all the contacts if the total width of my SlidingDrawer's handle + content is greater than the width of my screen (eg if there are more than 6 contacts to be shown in the bottom image shown below)?

Thanks

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'd try putting the drawer's content in a [`HorizontalScrollView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView.html), or using a [`Gallery`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Gallery.html).